# Nextjs13 use. When calling api from page.tsx "return NextResponse.fromBuffer(data);" I am stuck at this part. Is it possible to return a buffer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to get the value of buffer via nextjs API route.

nextjs version is 13.4.7

When I open the page `voicevox_test`, I first get the value `audioQuery` in `useEffect`. once I get the `audioQuer`y, I want to get the data that will be the audio in the second `useEffect`. I am stumped on the part of getting the audio data, I can fetch the data directly in `useEffect`, but I don't know how to go through the API route.
I want to use the return value as

```
return new Uint8Array(await res.arrayBuffer());
```

I get a 500 (Internal Server Error).

```
const data = await res.arrayBuffer();
return NextResponse.json(data);
```

then there is no error, but the desired data is not obtained.
I can fetch the data directly in `useEffect`, but I don't know how to go through the API route.

app/voicevox_test/page.tsx

```
'use client'
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Posttest() {
  const [audioQuery, setAudioQuery] = useState();
  const [synthesis, setSynthesis] = useState<Uint8Array>();
  const [src, setSrc] = useState<string>();

  const audioRef = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAudioQuery = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/voicevox_audio_query',
    {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify({text: 'Hello', speaker: '1'})
    }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('voicevox audio_query data: ', data)
    setAudioQuery(data);
    };
    fetchAudioQuery();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSynthesis = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/voicevox_synthesis',
    {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'arraybuffer',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({audioQuery: audioQuery, speaker: '1'})
    }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('data: ', data)
    };
    if (audioQuery != null) fetchSynthesis();
  }, [audioQuery]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (src && audioRef.current) {
    audioRef.current.muted = false;
    audioRef.current.play();
    // audioRef.current.controls = false;
    }
  }, [src]);

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
    post
    <audio muted playsInline controls autoPlay ref={audioRef} src={src} />
    {/* <iframe src={src} allow="autoplay" /> */}
    </main>
  )
}
```

app/api/voicevox_synthesis

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const req = await request.json();
  const params = new URLSearchParams({speaker: req.speaker});

  const url = `http://localhost:50021/synthesis?${params}`;
  const method = 'POST';
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'arraybuffer',
  };
  const body = JSON.stringify(req.audioQuery);
  try {

    const res = await fetch(url, {method, headers, body});
    if (!res.ok) {
    console.error(`HTTP error: ${res.status}`);
    return null;
    }

    const data = await res.arrayBuffer();
    return NextResponse.fromBuffer(data);

    // return new Uint8Array(await res.arrayBuffer());
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Network error: ${error}`);
    return null;
  }
}
```

I want to get the value obtained by the code below as the value of response in the `fetchSynthesis` of `useEffect`.

```
const res = await fetch(url, {method, headers, body});
    if (!res.ok) {
    console.error(`HTTP error: ${res.status}`);
    return null; }
    }

    const data = await res.arrayBuffer();
    return NextResponse.fromBuffer(data);
```

Comment: Please properly format your code using a formatter like [prettier](https://prettier.io/).